# How to get text to align alongside image if image is larger?

Tags: html, css

This is my code which works - used vehicle platform - HTML with flex, but isn't quite esthetically pleasing:

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

header.infog {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 30px;
}

footer.infog {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mainwrapper {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: table;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 900px;
}

.itemwrapper {
  display: table-row;
  width: 90px;
  margin-right: -40px;
}

.itemwrapper1 {
  display: table-row;
  margin-left: -356em;
  width: 100px;
}

.itemwrapper1 img {}

.some-page-wrapper {
  margin: 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 600px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.column1 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.priceg {
  font-size: 29px;
  color: red;
  padding-left: 500px;
}

.img-nac img {
  max-width: 330px;
}

.img-nac1 img {
  max-width: 460px;
}

.ncat {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: -450px;
  text-align: right 50px;
}

.ncat1 {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: -200px;
  text-align: right 50px;
}

.at1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.priceh {
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.mainwrapper {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Car , Van, Caravan Dealer | Quality Used Cars</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="infog">
    header
  </header>
  <div class='some-page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column1'>
        2003 TOYOTA RAV4 2.0 GX
      </div>
      <div class='column1 priceg'>
        £8995
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column img-nac'>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg/1280px-2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class='column ncat'>
        black
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='some-page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column1'>
        2003 TOYOTA RAV4 2.0 GX
      </div>
      <div class='column1 priceg'>
        £8995
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column img-nac1'>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg/1280px-2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class='column ncat'>
        rowtt
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='some-page-wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='column img-nac'>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg/1280px-2013_Toyota_RAV4_XLE_AWD_front_left.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class='column at1'>
        <h3>2004 TOYOTA RAV4 2.0</h4>
          black
      </div>
      <div class='column priceh'>
        <h3>£6000</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="infog">
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that I'm trying to make it so that if the image is large it's still alongside the text, like this from my page:
[image]
The blue line below is actually a bit of the next image... I didn't screencap well.

I've not figured out how to with the CSS and max-width size to do this, resulting in:
[image: Second image]

The car description in the second flexbox (column and ncat classes) doesn't show up.

But it works fine with the smaller image; I'm trying to make it big enough for people to see.

This isn't the final version, as I'm adding Roboto font etc. in the CSS, but it's almost working.

I'd much appreciate any advice on how to ensure I can get this to work in flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your CSS with the following code

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
  
  header.infog {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  footer.infog {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .mainwrapper {
    border: 2px solid;
    display: table;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 900px;
  }
  
  .itemwrapper {
    display: table-row;
    width: 90px;
    margin-right: -40px;
  }
  
  .itemwrapper1 {
    display: table-row;
    margin-left: -356em;
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  .some-page-wrapper {
    margin: 15px;
  }
  
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .column {
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .column1 {
    margin-left: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .priceg {
    font-size: 29px;
    color: red;
    padding-left: 500px;
  }
  
  .img-nac img {
    max-width: 330px;
  }
  
  .img-nac1 img {
    max-width: 460px;
  }
  
  .ncat {
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: right 50px;
  }
  
  .ncat1 {
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: right 50px;
  }
  
  .at1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  
  .priceh {
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  
  .mainwrapper {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```